# How can I count the occurrences of a segment finished by . in a large string?

Tags: php, string, count

I need to count the number of occurrences in a segment, that finish by a ".", in a large string and do it for all the segments in the string.

For example if I got this in a $str variable:

```
Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers following are few common myths and facts related to testing. Manual Testing is the most primitive of all testing types and helps find bugs in the software system. Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers manually execute test cases without using any automation tools. Manual Testing is the most primitive of all testing types and helps find bugs in the software system.
```

The expected output will be:

```
"There is 1 occurrence in your string"
```

Because one segment is repeated is the string, i was thinking of explode my str with "." as delimiter then use this function:

```
substr_count ( string $haystack , string $needle)
```

Any thoughts about this ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is unclear. What's the expected output?

Comment: I've tried to modified the question, idk if its clearer.

Comment: so you want to calculate repeated segments? I can see 4 sentences ending with `.`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, then compare the first sentence with all the str, second one with all the str, etc.

Comment: Still a bit unclear to me. How did you arrive at the output as `"There is 1 occurrence in your string"`? Which occurrence did you find and with whom you compared with?

Comment: If you consider (in this case) that a segment is delimited by "." char, we have 4 "segments" in my example:
 `1. Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers following are few common myths and facts related to testing.
2. Manual Testing is the most primitive of all testing types and helps find bugs in the software system.
3. Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers manually execute test cases without using any automation tools.
4. Manual Testing is the most primitive of all testing types and helps find bugs in the software system.`

Comment: I do know that as I already mentioned in my previous comments. But how did you arrive at `"There is 1 occurrence in your string"`?

Comment: If you see there are 2 segments there are the exactly the same, segment number "2" and "4". I call that an occurrence here. Now, to find the "There is 1 occurrence in your string" I will compare every segment with the other segments except himself. For example:
If i find segment n "1" to be exactly the same like the segments n "2", "3" or "4" = I will count the matches, in this case only the segment "2" is equal to segment "4"

Comment: sorry was writing, and I get you, its actually hard to explain...

Comment: This makes sense now. One last question. What should be the answer for [this case](https://pastebin.com/9VS8yscy)?

Comment: **4** occurrences, segment number 1 is the same as number 7, segment number 2 is the same as number 4 and finally segment number 3 is the same as numbers 5 and 6 (even if there is an space at the beginning of segment 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = 'Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers following are few common myths and facts related to testing. Manual Testing is the most primitive of all testing types and helps find bugs in the software system. Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers manually execute test cases without using any automation tools. Manual Testing is the most primitive of all testing types and helps find bugs in the software system. Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers manually execute test cases without using any automation tools.Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers manually execute test cases without using any automation tools. Manual Testing is a type of Software Testing where Testers following are few common myths and facts related to testing.';

$segment_data = array_count_values(array_map("trim",array_slice(explode(".",$str),0,-1)));

$occurrences = array_sum($segment_data) - count($segment_data);

echo "There are $occurrences occurrence(s) in your string";
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/eMcNX

- We first explode the string based on period(`.`) delimiter. Then, we do an [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to avoid the empty string found at the end. We then [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) it to make the segments nicer with the help of [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply to each segment in the exploded array of strings.
- Now, with the help of [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), we get the count of occurrence of each segment.
- We do an [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to sum all occurrences of all segments and subtract it from size of unique segments itself to get the no. of duplicate occurrences as you desired.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this work really well, and your explanation is really well done. Thanks for the lesson overall :)

Comment: @Satanas Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`substr_count` counts the number of occurrences of a given substring `$needle` appears in a string `$haystack`. That's not what you want.
You want [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), to be used after you explode the string.

If `$str` is your string, you can do:

```
$splitted = explode(".", $str);
$maxrepeated = max(array_count_values($splitted));
```

And `$maxrepeated` is max number of repetition (2 using your sample string).
If you want repetition beyond first, just subtract `1` from `$maxrepeated`.